# How to add Icon to the hintText in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add Icon to the hintText field of the TextFormField. I already read about prefixIcons and SuffixIcons but they add the icons permanently. I want Icon as a hintText so that when User click it disappears like hintText. How can I achieve this in flutter

Answer (score 4):

You can't achieve that with a property of TextFormField but you can change the visibility of the Icon based on the controller of the Field:

```
bool isVisible = true;
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        onChanged: (text){
          setState(() {
            controller.text.isEmpty ? isVisible = true : isVisible = false;
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'hintText',
          prefixIcon: Visibility(
            visible: isVisible,
            child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.grey,),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

@override
void dispose() {
  controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LOfG

Comment: prefix icon do not add icon in the starting of the hint text
``` hello world``` can't do that with prefixicon

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you!

[image: This is how the output looks like.]

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? hintText;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry outsidePadding, contentPadding;

  SearchInputWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.hintText = "Search",
    this.outsidePadding = const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18, bottom: 0),
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(16),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SearchInputWidget> createState() => _SearchInputWidgetState();
}

class _SearchInputWidgetState extends State<SearchInputWidget> {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> hintVisibilityNotifier = ValueNotifier(true);

  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: widget.outsidePadding,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            controller: textEditingController,
            style: TextStyle(
                // color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: "Asap",
                fontSize: 20),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                contentPadding: widget.contentPadding),
            onChanged: (text) {
              if (text.isEmpty) {
                hintVisibilityNotifier.value = true;
              } else {
                hintVisibilityNotifier.value = false;
              }
            },
            onEditingComplete: () {
              if (textEditingController.text.isEmpty) {
                hintVisibilityNotifier.value = true;
              } else {
                hintVisibilityNotifier.value = false;
              }
            },
          ),
          ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: hintVisibilityNotifier,
              builder: (BuildContext context, bool isVisible, Widget? child) {
                if (isVisible) {
                  return Positioned.fill(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: IgnorePointer(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                              size: 26,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              widget.hintText!,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                                fontFamily: "Asap",
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                }
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ResultPage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration:
            InputDecoration(
 prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
    hintText: "hello this is a hint text")
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).